# Power BI DAX Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am designing a DAX to calculate, there are two categories of subjects, one is compulsory and other is normal. My DAX needs to check, if the marks are within the range for allocation of Satutory marks.The Statutory Marks are fixed at 5.

As an example if I have 5 Subjects, with marks 13 for Compulsory and 16,15,16,17,25 for the normal ones.

The DAX should allocate 4 marks to the compulsory and bring it to 17[Passing Marks] and remaining 2 should go to 16/16 so that they are pass. All other would remain as they are. I have compiled a DAX, not sure were I am wrong.

```
MehrajCalc_Measure = 
VAR Marks_obtained = MAX(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS])  // Considering the maximum marks obtained within the current context
VAR Min_Marks = MAX(ExamTbl_MIN_PassMarks[Diet_categoryInfo.Diet_minMarks])
VAR StatueMarks = 5

VAR Compulsory_Marks = 
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] ),
        Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "compulsory" &&
        Marks_obtained >= 12 && Marks_obtained < Min_Marks
    )

VAR NormalMarks =     
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] ),
        Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal" &&
        Marks_obtained >= 12 && Marks_obtained < Min_Marks
    )

VAR Remaining_Statue_Marks = MAX(StatueMarks - Compulsory_Marks, 0)

VAR Remaining_Statue_Marks_Normal = IF(Remaining_Statue_Marks > 0, MAX(0, Remaining_Statue_Marks - NormalMarks), Remaining_Statue_Marks)

VAR StatueMarksToAdd = 
    IF(
        Remaining_Statue_Marks_Normal > 0,
        IF(Min_Marks - Marks_obtained > Remaining_Statue_Marks_Normal, Remaining_Statue_Marks_Normal, Min_Marks - Marks_obtained),
        0
    )

RETURN 
    IF(
        Marks_obtained >= 12 && Marks_obtained < Min_Marks,
        Marks_obtained +  StatueMarksToAdd,
        Marks_obtained
    )
```

Comment: You can provide sample data with expected output in new column in tabular format. Just explanation not makes everything clear every-time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, logically

```
MehrajCalc_Measure =
VAR Marks_obtained = MAX(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS])
VAR Min_Marks = MAX(ExamTbl_MIN_PassMarks[Diet_categoryInfo.Diet_minMarks])
VAR StatueMarks = 5

VAR Compulsory_Marks =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX(
            FILTER(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "compulsory"),
            IF(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 && Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks, Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS], 0)
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectID])
    )

VAR Normal_Marks =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX(
            FILTER(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal"),
            IF(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 && Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks, Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS], 0)
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectID])
    )

VAR Remaining_Statue_Marks = MAX(StatueMarks - Compulsory_Marks, 0)

VAR Remaining_Marks_To_Distribute =
    VAR Normal_Marks_Needs_Boost =
        CALCULATE(
            SUMX(
                FILTER(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal"),
                IF(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 && Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks - Remaining_Statue_Marks, Min_Marks - Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS], 0)
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectID])
        )
    RETURN
        IF(Normal_Marks_Needs_Boost > Remaining_Statue_Marks, Remaining_Statue_Marks, Normal_Marks_Needs_Boost)

VAR Marks_To_Add_To_Current_Row =
    IF(
        Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "compulsory" &&
            Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 &&
            Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks,
        MIN(Remaining_Statue_Marks, Min_Marks - Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS]),
        IF(
            Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal" &&
                Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 &&
                Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks,
            MIN(Remaining_Marks_To_Distribute, Min_Marks - Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS]),
            0
        )
    )

RETURN
    Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] + Marks_To_Add_To_Current_Row
```

I have replaced, `SUM`with `SUMX`, made use of `ALLEXCEPT` and introduced a new variable named `Remaining_Marks_To_Distribute`. I also hope that you will be able to decipher the changes.

One Advise, if **Mehraj** is a name of a person, the norm of software solution is never to use individual names as part of variable names.

**DAX MODIFIED AFTER SAMPLE DATA**

```
MehrajCalc_Measure =
VAR Marks_obtained = MAX(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS])
VAR Min_Marks = MAX(ExamTbl_MIN_PassMarks[Diet_categoryInfo.Diet_minMarks])
VAR StatueMarks = 5

VAR Compulsory_Marks =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX(
            FILTER(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "compulsory"),
            IF(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 && Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks, Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS], 0)
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectID])
    )

VAR Normal_Marks =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX(
            FILTER(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal"),
            Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS]
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectID])
    )

VAR Remaining_Statue_Marks = MAX(StatueMarks - Compulsory_Marks, 0)

VAR Remaining_Marks_To_Distribute =
    VAR Normal_Marks_Needs_Boost =
        CALCULATE(
            SUMX(
                FILTER(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal"),
                IF(Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks - Remaining_Statue_Marks, Min_Marks - Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS], 0)
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT(Test_Analytics, Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectID])
        )
    RETURN
        IF(Normal_Marks_Needs_Boost > Remaining_Statue_Marks, Remaining_Statue_Marks, Normal_Marks_Needs_Boost)

VAR Marks_To_Add_To_Current_Row =
    IF(
        Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "compulsory" &&
            Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 &&
            Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks,
        MIN(Remaining_Statue_Marks, Min_Marks - Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS]),
        IF(
            Test_Analytics[examScore.Diet_subjectType] = "normal" &&
                Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] >= 12 &&
                Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] < Min_Marks,
            MIN(Remaining_Marks_To_Distribute, Min_Marks - Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS]),
            0
        )
    )

RETURN
    Test_Analytics[TOTAL_MarksObtained_FAS] + Marks_To_Add_To_Current_Row
```

**Compulsory Subject** (14 Marks):
Marks obtained = 14 (original) + 3 (from the statue) = 17 Marks

**Normal Subjects**:
15 Marks: Marks obtained = 15 (original) + 2 (from the statue) = 17 Marks
16 Marks: Marks obtained = 16 (original) + 1 (from the statue) = 17 Marks
16 Marks: Marks obtained = 16 (original) + 1 (from the statue) = 17 Marks
17 Marks: Marks obtained = 17 (original) (already meets the passing marks)

Comment: So If I have a subjectlist like below:
Compulsory Subject has 14 Marks.
Passing Marks 17 Marks.
Statue Has 5 Marks.
Normal Subjects have, 15,16,16,17 Marks ( we need to sort them in DESC).
Output should be 14+3(from statue) = 17.
16+1 = 17 and 16+1 = 17 for the other two.

Please let me know if we need to change the DAX. Above is pulling 0 for all.

Comment: I missed to include that, Statue are fixed, They are 5, so if 3 are utilized in Compulsary then remaining 2 must go to 16 and 16 to scale them up to 17. All others would remain as same.

Can you please look into this, Thanks,